# What's the difference between ImplicitlyWait and RetryingElementLocator regarding PageObject?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageobjects

**When** I use PageObject **and** I want to set a time to wait for elements on the page **then** I use ImplicitlyWait:

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

**This means that when** my page object is initializing:

```
PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
```

**Then** it will wait for elements not less then 3 seconds.

**Also there is another feature of Selenium that I discovered recently:** [RetryingElementLocator class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_RetryingElementLocator.htm)

**Code of this class:** https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_RetryingElementLocator.htm

As I understand it allows to set time to wait elements on a page for PageObject.

**The example of usage is the next:**

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
RetryingElementLocator retry = new RetryingElementLocator(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IPageObjectMemberDecorator decor = new DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator();
PageFactory.InitElements(retry.SearchContext, this, decor);
```

**So the question is:** if there is any difference between 2 methods and if so when it's better to use the second one?

Comment: no i guess both is different one is implicit wait applicable to all but RetryingElementLocator  is Explicit wait applicable for a specific webelement

Comment: But it applies to all elements in a PageObject. But if you are right then the question is what is the difference between WebDriverWait Untill method and RetryingElementLocator?

Comment: yes RetryingElementLocator acts as a webdriverwait (java) and Until works with expected conditions